# Legend without a range of color

Tags: r

The following script gives me a graph with a legend in a range of colors between `Vc=30` and `Vc=40`. All I need is to have a legend with only two colors, one for `Vc=30` and other for `Vc=40`. How can I do that?

```
dados
    Vc Tool  Lu Fres Edge
1   30    1  10  466    1
2   30    1  10  416    2
3   30    1  10  465    1
4   30    1  10  416    2
5   30    1  10  464    1
6   30    1  10  416    2
7   30    1  10  476    1
8   30    1  10  412    2
9   30    1  10  468    1
10  30    1  10  410    2
11  30    1  10  470    1
12  30    1  10  407    2
13  30    1  10  468    1
14  30    1  10  412    2
15  30    1  10  469    1
16  30    1  10  414    2
17  30    1  10  469    1
18  30    1  10  412    2
19  30    1  10  467    1
20  30    1  10  409    2
21  30    1  10  469    1
22  30    1  10  415    2
23  30    1  10  471    1
24  30    1  10  420    2
25  30    1  10  469    1
26  30    1  10  416    2
27  30    1  10  464    1
28  30    1  10  409    2
29  30    1  10  465    1
30  30    1  10  412    2
31  30    1  10  464    1
32  30    1  10  409    2
33  30    1  10  466    1
34  30    1  10  417    2
35  30    1  10  466    1
36  30    1  10  417    2
37  30    1  10  464    1
38  30    1  10  414    2
39  30    1  10  466    1
40  30    1  10  415    2
41  40    1  38  457    1
42  40    1  38  416    2
43  40    1  38  460    1
44  40    1  38  438    2
45  40    1  38  465    1
46  40    1  38  441    2
47  40    1  38  467    1
48  40    1  38  442    2
49  40    1  38  473    1
50  40    1  38  452    2
51  40    1  38  469    1
52  40    1  38  446    2
53  40    1  38  478    1
54  40    1  38  450    2
55  40    1  38  476    1
56  40    1  38  454    2
57  40    1  38  479    1
58  40    1  38  452    2
59  40    1  38  480    1
60  40    1  38  450    2
61  40    1  38  481    1
62  40    1  38  443    2
63  40    1  38  476    1
64  40    1  38  447    2
65  40    1  38  472    1
66  40    1  38  450    2
67  40    1  38  479    1
68  40    1  38  449    2
69  40    1  38  478    1
70  40    1  38  455    2
71  40    1  38  478    1
72  40    1  38  457    2
73  40    1  38  481    1
74  40    1  38  447    2
75  40    1  38  504    1
76  40    1  38  452    2
77  40    1  38  472    1
78  40    1  38  447    2
79  40    1  38  472    1
80  40    1  38  451    2
81  40    1  66  622    1
82  40    1  66  377    2
83  40    1  66  619    1
84  40    1  66  378    2
85  40    1  66  622    1
86  40    1  66  369    2
87  40    1  66  616    1
88  40    1  66  374    2
89  40    1  66  619    1
90  40    1  66  374    2
91  40    1  66  616    1
92  40    1  66  374    2
93  40    1  66  621    1
94  40    1  66  375    2
95  40    1  66  618    1
96  40    1  66  397    2
97  40    1  66  633    1
98  40    1  66  406    2
99  40    1  66  652    1
100 40    1  66  412    2
101 40    1  66  652    1
102 40    1  66  419    2
103 40    1  66  658    1
104 40    1  66  423    2
105 40    1  66  659    1
106 40    1  66  409    2
107 40    1  66  650    1
108 40    1  66  405    2
109 40    1  66  653    1
110 40    1  66  405    2
111 40    1  66  652    1
112 40    1  66  403    2
113 40    1  66  656    1
114 40    1  66  408    2
115 40    1  66  644    1
116 40    1  66  406    2
117 40    1  66  649    1
118 40    1  66  412    2
119 40    1  66  650    1
120 40    1  66  406    2
121 30    1  94  585    1
122 30    1  94  234    2
123 30    1  94  589    1
124 30    1  94  231    2
125 30    1  94  585    1
126 30    1  94  223    2
127 30    1  94  586    1
128 30    1  94  223    2
129 30    1  94  572    1
130 30    1  94  233    2
131 30    1  94  585    1
132 30    1  94  233    2
133 30    1  94  589    1
134 30    1  94  234    2
135 30    1  94  598    1
136 30    1  94  237    2
137 30    1  94  605    1
138 30    1  94  237    2
139 30    1  94  586    1
140 30    1  94  233    2
141 30    1  94  588    1
142 30    1  94  227    2
143 30    1  94  585    1
144 30    1  94  230    2
145 30    1  94  586    1
146 30    1  94  230    2
147 30    1  94  591    1
148 30    1  94  237    2
149 30    1  94  586    1
150 30    1  94  234    2
151 30    1  94  592    1
152 30    1  94  237    2
153 30    1  94  595    1
154 30    1  94  236    2
155 30    1  94  600    1
156 30    1  94  227    2
157 30    1  94  592    1
158 30    1  94  237    2
159 30    1  94  592    1
160 30    1  94  240    2
161 40    1 122  853    1
162 40    1 122  330    2
163 40    1 122  859    1
164 40    1 122  323    2
165 40    1 122  842    1
166 40    1 122  308    2
167 40    1 122  842    1
168 40    1 122  324    2
169 40    1 122  831    1
170 40    1 122  334    2
171 40    1 122  838    1
172 40    1 122  341    2
173 40    1 122  836    1
174 40    1 122  328    2
175 40    1 122  840    1
176 40    1 122  324    2
177 40    1 122  836    1
178 40    1 122  321    2
179 40    1 122  831    1
180 40    1 122  328    2
181 40    1 122  833    1
182 40    1 122  328    2
183 40    1 122  840    1
184 40    1 122  330    2
185 40    1 122  831    1
186 40    1 122  321    2
187 40    1 122  833    1
188 40    1 122  328    2
189 40    1 122  833    1
190 40    1 122  321    2
191 40    1 122  840    1
192 40    1 122  319    2
193 40    1 122  838    1
194 40    1 122  317    2
195 40    1 122  831    1
196 40    1 122  319    2
197 40    1 122  827    1
198 40    1 122  323    2
199 40    1 122  836    1
200 40    1 122  328    2
201 30    2  10  468    1
202 30    2  10  408    2
203 30    2  10  471    1
204 30    2  10  405    2
205 30    2  10  475    1
206 30    2  10  403    2
207 30    2  10  470    1
208 30    2  10  409    2
209 30    2  10  478    1
210 30    2  10  405    2
211 30    2  10  474    1
212 30    2  10  403    2
213 30    2  10  472    1
214 30    2  10  402    2
215 30    2  10  478    1
216 30    2  10  408    2
217 30    2  10  477    1
218 30    2  10  406    2
219 30    2  10  473    1
220 30    2  10  406    2
221 30    2  10  474    1
222 30    2  10  406    2
223 30    2  10  477    1
224 30    2  10  411    2
225 30    2  10  480    1
226 30    2  10  413    2
227 30    2  10  479    1
228 30    2  10  408    2
229 30    2  10  476    1
230 30    2  10  406    2
231 30    2  10  476    1
232 30    2  10  404    2
233 30    2  10  472    1
234 30    2  10  407    2
235 30    2  10  474    1
236 30    2  10  411    2
237 30    2  10  473    1
238 30    2  10  415    2
239 30    2  10  479    1
240 30    2  10  409    2
241 40    2  38  442    1
242 40    2  38  407    2
243 40    2  38  437    1
244 40    2  38  410    2
245 40    2  38  444    1
246 40    2  38  412    2
247 40    2  38  440    1
248 40    2  38  414    2
249 40    2  38  439    1
250 40    2  38  413    2
251 40    2  38  436    1
252 40    2  38  416    2
253 40    2  38  446    1
254 40    2  38  412    2
255 40    2  38  438    1
256 40    2  38  414    2
257 40    2  38  443    1
258 40    2  38  408    2
259 40    2  38  446    1
260 40    2  38  407    2
261 40    2  38  445    1
262 40    2  38  413    2
263 40    2  38  453    1
264 40    2  38  414    2
265 40    2  38  449    1
266 40    2  38  417    2
267 40    2  38  447    1
268 40    2  38  411    2
269 40    2  38  443    1
270 40    2  38  417    2
271 40    2  38  447    1
272 40    2  38  410    2
273 40    2  38  449    1
274 40    2  38  409    2
275 40    2  38  442    1
276 40    2  38  413    2
277 40    2  38  451    1
278 40    2  38  412    2
279 40    2  38  447    1
280 40    2  38  420    2
281 40    2  66  526    1
282 40    2  66  467    2
283 40    2  66  532    1
284 40    2  66  470    2
285 40    2  66  528    1
286 40    2  66  474    2
287 40    2  66  529    1
288 40    2  66  472    2
289 40    2  66  533    1
290 40    2  66  480    2
291 40    2  66  542    1
292 40    2  66  487    2
293 40    2  66  545    1
294 40    2  66  504    2
295 40    2  66  549    1
296 40    2  66  507    2
297 40    2  66  546    1
298 40    2  66  517    2
299 40    2  66  541    1
300 40    2  66  518    2
301 40    2  66  554    1
302 40    2  66  514    2
303 40    2  66  564    1
304 40    2  66  514    2
305 40    2  66  571    1
306 40    2  66  522    2
307 40    2  66  575    1
308 40    2  66  525    2
309 40    2  66  582    1
310 40    2  66  533    2
311 40    2  66  588    1
312 40    2  66  536    2
313 40    2  66  591    1
314 40    2  66  553    2
315 40    2  66  592    1
316 40    2  66  557    2
317 40    2  66  592    1
318 40    2  66  563    2
319 40    2  66  583    1
320 40    2  66  568    2
321 30    2  94  578    1
322 30    2  94  370    2
323 30    2  94  570    1
324 30    2  94  378    2
325 30    2  94  575    1
326 30    2  94  367    2
327 30    2  94  579    1
328 30    2  94  371    2
329 30    2  94  576    1
330 30    2  94  362    2
331 30    2  94  579    1
332 30    2  94  372    2
333 30    2  94  588    1
334 30    2  94  375    2
335 30    2  94  586    1
336 30    2  94  372    2
337 30    2  94  589    1
338 30    2  94  378    2
339 30    2  94  587    1
340 30    2  94  375    2
341 30    2  94  578    1
342 30    2  94  368    2
343 30    2  94  575    1
344 30    2  94  375    2
345 30    2  94  574    1
346 30    2  94  376    2
347 30    2  94  575    1
348 30    2  94  367    2
349 30    2  94  580    1
350 30    2  94  382    2
351 30    2  94  583    1
352 30    2  94  368    2
353 30    2  94  591    1
354 30    2  94  386    2
355 30    2  94  595    1
356 30    2  94  379    2
357 30    2  94  593    1
358 30    2  94  384    2
359 30    2  94  607    1
360 30    2  94  399    2
361 30    2 122  760    1
362 30    2 122  625    2
363 30    2 122  746    1
364 30    2 122  612    2
365 30    2 122  762    1
366 30    2 122  625    2
367 30    2 122  783    1
368 30    2 122  637    2
369 30    2 122  778    1
370 30    2 122  640    2
371 30    2 122  778    1
372 30    2 122  638    2
373 30    2 122  791    1
374 30    2 122  638    2
375 30    2 122  782    1
376 30    2 122  635    2
377 30    2 122  792    1
378 30    2 122  640    2
379 30    2 122  783    1
380 30    2 122  637    2
381 30    2 122  774    1
382 30    2 122  622    2
383 30    2 122  777    1
384 30    2 122  618    2
385 30    2 122  777    1
386 30    2 122  622    2
387 30    2 122  765    1
388 30    2 122  623    2
389 30    2 122  769    1
390 30    2 122  625    2
391 30    2 122  775    1
392 30    2 122  622    2
393 30    2 122  777    1
394 30    2 122  628    2
395 30    2 122  769    1
396 30    2 122  620    2
397 30    2 122  778    1
398 30    2 122  623    2
399 30    2 122  788    1
400 30    2 122  634    2
> dadosc <- summarySE(dados, measurevar="Fres", groupvars=c("Vc","Lu"))
> dadosc
  Vc  Lu  N     Fres        sd        se        ci
1 30  10 80 440.6875  30.91540  3.456447  6.879885
2 30  94 80 445.0250 150.97028 16.878990 33.596789
3 30 122 40 701.7000  75.06688 11.869115 24.007552
4 40  38 80 444.6125  23.31973  2.607225  5.189552
5 40  66 80 526.7125  90.77824 10.149316 20.201707
6 40 122 40 581.1250 259.74092 41.068645 83.069175

ggplot(dadosc, aes(x=Lu, y=Fres,ymax=max(Fres), colour=Vc)) +
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Fres-se, ymax=Fres+se), colour="black", width=2, position=pd) +
 geom_point(position=pd, size=3, shape=21, fill="white") +
 xlab("Machining lenght (mm)") +
 ylab("Machining forces (N)") +
 ggtitle("The Effect of Cutting Velocity on Machining Forces") +
 expand_limits(y=400) +                        # Expand y range
 scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:20*50) +         # Set tick every 4
 theme_bw() +
 theme(legend.justification=c(1,0),
 legend.position=c(1,0))
 pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
```

Comment: try using `colour = factor(Vc)`.  Scales are handled differently for numeric and categorical values.

Comment: @Benjamin or recode the data first using `dadosc$Vc <- factor(dadosc$Vc)`